# C# vs Java generics. How to convert this piece of code to Java?

Tags: java, c#, generics

Following is a C# method that calls by any childpage (context is automation and page object model)

```
//A method of ParentPage (C#)
protected static ChildPage NavigateToPage<ChildPage>(string url) where ChildPage : ParentPage, new()
{
   // do something with the url
   //
   ChildPage destinationPage = new ChildPage();
   return destinationPage;
}
```

Above method gets called as follows,

```
NavigatetoPage<HomePage>("LoginButton");
```

or

```
NavigatetoPage<DocumentEditPage>("DocumentItemOnList");
```

I am unable to convert the above method to Java. I have read multiple documents and examples but I can't achieve it. I think Java didn't support this scenario. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Generics use type erasure, which basically means that the same method implementation is used no matter what the type parameter is.

To do this kind of thing in Java, you have to do:

```
static <ChildPage extends ParentPage> ChildPage NavigateToPage(Class<ChildPage> cls, String url)
{
   // do something with the url
   //
   ChildPage destinationPage = cls.newInstance();
   return destinationPage;
}
```

and call it like this:

```
NavigatetoPage(HomePage.class, "LoginButton");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your thought is correct: you cannot instantiate an instance from a type parameter (`ChildPage` in your example).  This is a side-effect of how Java implements generics through Type Erasure, which basically means that all the generic type safety happens at compile time.

This contrasts with C#, which still has the generic type information available at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with java 8, you can do this conveniently and without reflection:

```
<C extends ParentPage> C navigateToPage(String url, Supplier<C> pageFactory) {
    // do whatever
    C destination = pageFactory.get();
    return destination;
}
```

Then you would call it with a lambda expression or method reference:

```
HomePage home = navigateToPage("Login", HomePage::new);
```

This is fully type-safe and gives you the flexibility to inject a supplier other than a default constructor.  For example, suppose you maintain a cache of `HomePage` instances:

```
HomePage home = navigateToPage("Login", homePageCache::get);
```

Or, perhaps you already have the `HomePage` object constructed and want `navigateToPage` to work on that one instead of a new one:

```
HomePage home = new HomePage();
navigateToPage("Login", () -> home);
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have to pass a `Class` object as a parameter:

```
protected static <P extends ParentPage> P navigateToPage(Class<P> childPage, String url) {
   // do something with the url
   //
   P destinationPage = childPage.newInstance();
   return destinationPage;
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to guarantee `P` has a parameterless constructor at compile time.